# Giving access to cron job php file just to server

Tags: php, cron

I have wrote a php file for having cronjob in my server, but the problem is that every one can access to that.

I just want to give access to cronjob file , Just to server and nothing more.

How can i do this ?

Can we do it by getting user ip and server ip and if it was not server ip file gets die?

Is it good way?

Any better way?

Comment: Why not use simple file permissions to allow only the cron user to be able to access the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this file in root home folder or every place that root has permission to access that